# Spherical Cosinus Haversine Formula

Tags: java, android, haversine

So currently i write a function haversine formula to calculate distance for 2 coordinate, and i find this code but i dont know how to write it in android. here is the function that i will created. this

```
private double SphericalCosinus(double lat1, double long1, double lat2,
        double long2) {
    //formula
}
```

and the formula is this one, there is some tutorial that tell me to use math libarary but i always write the code wrong because the apps didnt show the location. here is the formula i get

```
=(6371.1*((2*ASIN(SQRT((SIN((RADIANS(lat2)-RADIANS(lat1))/2)^2)+COS(RADIANS(lat2))*COS(RADIANS(lat1))*(SIN((RADIANS(long2)-RADIANS(long1))/2)^2))))))
```

Comment: What is your question, actually?

Comment: i try to write it in android studio

Comment: The IDE is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

By the power of find and replace:

```
private double SphericalCosinus(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2) {
    return 6371.1*((2 * 
        Math.asin(
            Math.sqrt(
                (Math.sin(Math.pow((Math.toRadians(lat2)-Math.toRadians(lat1))/2),2.0)) + 
                Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * 
                Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) *
                (Math.sin(Math.pow(Math.toRadians(long2)-Math.toRadians(long1))/2),2.0)
            )
        )
    ));
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: operator  " ^ " cannot be applied to 'double','int', that is another error

Comment: I think it's a good practice that you will fix it yourself. Use Math.pow.

Comment: I've edited the answer so it will probably work. If you please with the answer, please submit it as the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, still error.....
pow (double, double) in Math cannot be applied to double